# Multiple "screens"

Tags: java, swing, awt, custom-component

I've been working quite a bit on a game, not too fancy, and i was wondering on what the best way to make a menu screen would be. I am currently using a single `JPanel` as the foundation for 
"painting." I was wondering what the best way to implement Menu Screens etc. would be.

What I thought of so far:

a) Have the current `JPanel` take care of the Menu screen.

b) Make new `JPanel`s for them and swap them to the next one; ex: If i hit the new game option, then switch to a new `JPanel` that holds the Game setup.

Extra Question:

Is it better to us a `Canvas` or some other component over a `JPanel`, given play-ability on an Applet and an Application was a concern?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recommendations:

- If this is a Swing application, then by all means stick with Swing components such as JPanels.
- Your users will probably prefer your swapping JPanels, and if you decide to go this route, the [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) will make it easy to do.
- You will probably want to swap JPanels if the views presented in them are significantly different. If it's only a matter of changing text though, then you could possibly get by with changing the text of several JLabels instead of swapping.

Comment: +1 Good advice; implementing `Icon`, illustrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513), is another convenient way to customize the graphics of an existing `JComponent.`

Answer (score 2):

From your question I am guessing that your game view is drawn entirely with `Graphics` inside `paintComponent()`, and there aren't any other components already in your main `JPanel`. In that situation it is probably cleaner to just switch which drawing code you call rather than having the other drawing code in an entirely different panel class.

**Edit:**

Just to clarify: The main reason you would want to swap `JPanel`s is if the original JPanel had a lot of components, listeners, etc. installed on it that you need to swap out in order to switch it to displaying the menu. If the menu screen can be painted to the same `Graphics` and be run by the same `MouseListener`, I would use just a single panel.

Comment: It looks like he has drawing screens for the game, and then wants to switch to menu screens.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That is the case.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it better to us a `Canvas` or some other component over a `JPanel`, given play-ability on an Applet and an Application was a concern?

Don't use a `Canvas` unless the rest of the project uses AWT.  If it is Swing, and a component contains *only* custom painting, use a `JComponent`.  If Swing and the area has components laid out inside it, use a `JPanel`.

Why did you make a distinction between an applet and application?  Are you thinking of using AWT in the applet, by any chance?

Comment: I made the distinction simply to make the point that I wanted to be able to run it on both an Applet and a windowed Application. I normally use the JApplet.